# Add styling to translation string in i18n-js React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, translation, i18n-js

I use i18n-js for translation purposes in my React Native app. But I cannot get any styling like different colors, bold etc. to my translations.

This is my en.js:

```
import {Text} from "react-native";

  const highlightText = (string) =>
    string.split(" ").map((word, i) => (
      <Text key={i}>
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEAFF", color: "#5F5C7E" }}>
          {word}
        </Text>
      </Text>
    ));

const en = {
   testTranslation:`This Text has some styling to it: ${highlightText("<h1>Hello</h1>")} isn't that pretty?`,
```

I use the translation on my screen like this:

```
import i18n from "i18n-js";
import { de } from "../../../locales/de";
import { en } from "../../../locales/en";
import { fr } from "../../../locales/fr";

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, de, fr };

...
 <Text>
     {i18n.t("testTranslation")}
 </Text>
```

The outcome is this:

> This Text has some styling to it: [object Object] isn't that pretty?

Any help how to style the text is much appreciated!

Comment: I hope you are using styled component.
I guess apply style on Text tag should work for you:

 <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEAFF", color: "#5F5C7E" }}>
     {i18n.t("testTranslation")}
 </Text>

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I do not use styled  components though :-/

Comment: You can control the same using ClassName too. like below:

<Text className="syleIt">
     {i18n.t("testTranslation")}
 </Text>

Now you have to make sure to define css class within you project.

Comment: Hey - again thank you for your answer! Adding styling within <Text> in my screen component does work. My issue is though that I have to break text into several pieces. For example: "This is a bold text" would be `<Text>{i18n.t("testTranslation_Part_1")}</Text><Text style={styles.TextBold}>{i18n.t("testTranslation_Part_2(bold)")}</Text><Text>{i18n.t("testTranslation_Part_3")}</Text>` Any idea how I could make this a bit more practical? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use syntax something like this

Create 3 string in translation file. Example

in translation files

```
str1: 'this is"
str2: 'bold'
str3: 'copy'
```

Now you can do something like

```
<>
  <Text>{i18n.t(str1)}</Text>
  <Text className="boldStyle">{i18n.t(str2)}</Text>
  <Text>{i18n.t(str3)}</Text>
<>
```

There are other patterns for the same. but this is clean and small

Comment: This is really a bad solution... This will never work for RTL languages, but for a lot more languages it will never produce a good translation. This only works for the first main language and languages which are similar. But a lot of languages have different ordering of the words in a sentence. Besides the fact that you now have three separate translation entries without context (mainly an issue if you are not translating your app yourself, for example external translators).